# Initializing a hash with an empty array keyed to an array of strings - Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization

I have:

```
people=["Bob","Fred","Sam"]

holidays = Hash.new 
people.each do |person|
  a=Array.new
  holidays[person]=a
end

gifts = Hash.new
people.each do |person|
  a=Array.new
  gifts[person]=a
end
```

Feels clunky.  I can't seem to figure a more streamline way with an initialization block or somesuch thing.  Is there an idiomatic approach here?

Ideally, I'd like to keep an array like:

```
lists["holidays","gifts",...]
```

... and itterate through it to initialize each element in the lists array.

Comment: A structure like `{ gifts: [ ], holidays: [ ] }` for each person might make more sense than having it structured in the inverse way, with holidays broken out by person, and gifts by person.

Comment: This seems like an assignment question.

Answer (score 1):

```
people = %w|Bob Fred Sam|
data = %w|holidays gifts|

result = data.zip(data.map { people.zip(people.map { [] }).to_h }).to_h
result['holidays']['Bob'] << Date.today
#⇒ {
#    "holidays" => {
#         "Bob" => [
#           [0] #<Date: 2016-11-04 ((2457697j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
#         ],
#        "Fred" => [],
#         "Sam" => []
#    },
#       "gifts" => {
#         "Bob" => [],
#        "Fred" => [],
#         "Sam" => []
#    }
# }
```

More sophisticated example would be:

```
result = data.map do |d| 
  [d, Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] if people.include?(k) }]
end.to_h
```

The latter produces the “lazy initialized nested hashes.” It uses the [`Hash#new` with a block](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) constructor for nested hashes.

Play with it to see how it works.

Comment: Interesting. Seems this actually makes a hash of hashes. It's not what I asked for, but it might actually be preferable for my purposes. Thank you

Comment: Oh.  Thanks. I will.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing that would be to use [Enumerable#each_with_objrect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

```
holidays = people.each_with_object({}) { |p,h| h[p] = [] }
  #=> {"Bob"=>[], "Fred"=>[], "Sam"=>[]}
```

`gifts` is the same.

Comment: Oh, indeed, `people.map { |p| [p, []] }.to_h`?

Comment: @mudasobwa, call me quirky, but there's something about converting an array to a hash that bugs me, at least when other methods are available. Same with converting a string to an array, manipulating the array then joining to produce a string. I'm happier if I can manipulate the string directly. (Not that I would lose sleep...)

Comment: Honestly, I do 102% agree, but the lazy beast inside me always wins the battle with “less to type” argument :)

Answer (score -1):

If you only want a number of such hashes then, the following should suffice:

```
count_of_hashes = 4 // lists.count; 4 is chosen randomly by throwing a fair die

people = ["Bob", "Fred", "Sam"]

lists = count_of_hashes.times.map do
  people.map {|person| [person, []]}.to_h
end
```

This code also ensures the arrays and the hashes all occupy their own memory. As can be verified by the following code:

```
holidays, gifts, *rest = lists
holidays["Bob"] << "Rome"
```

And checking the values of all the other hashes:

```
lists
=> [
    {"Bob"=>["Rome"], "Fred"=>[], "Sam"=>[]},
    {"Bob"=>[], "Fred"=>[], "Sam"=>[]},
    {"Bob"=>[], "Fred"=>[], "Sam"=>[]},
    {"Bob"=>[], "Fred"=>[], "Sam"=>[]}
   ]
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Why the n=3?  Why the 3.times.map?

Comment: n is however many such hashes you want to initialise. 3.times.map needs to be changed to n.times.map.

Comment: There's no reason at all to use that. The `people` array can be remapped directly.

Comment: In the original question the length of the `people` array dictates how many entries to create. Here, for reasons unexplained, 3 makes an appearance.

Comment: Interesting. The OP mentions `lists["holidays","gifts",...]` in his question. He is trying to initialise multiple such hashes. n is the number of such hashes in the array `lists`. n as 3 is an example. @tadman Does this clear up the confusion? n = 3 is NOT the number of persons in the people array.

Comment: This is why "magical" values like this are trouble. Normally you bind them intrinsically to something: `lists.length` or `lists.each` or anything that communicates the intent.

Comment: @tadman
Since `lists` isn't created yet, there is no way to bind it. You do have a valid point regarding non descriptive variable names. I have updated the answer accordingly. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just make an example `lists` if that's necessary. What you have here seems like random code.

Comment: ... Still random?